# Python datetime day light saving issue?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I am wondering why the delta is 3601 seconds when it should be 1 second:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

# Create eastern timezone
eastern = tz.gettz('America/New_York')

# 2017-03-12 01:59:59 in Eastern Time (EST)
spring_ahead_159am = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 1, 59, 59, tzinfo = eastern)

# 2017-03-12 03:00:00 in Eastern Time (EDT)
spring_ahead_3am = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo = eastern)

(spring_ahead_3am - spring_ahead_159am).seconds
3601
```

Please explain me what I am doing wrong? Why it's not giving me 1 second diff?

P.S:

Please explain why this will do work easily:
Let:

```
EST = timezone(timedelta(hours=-5))
EDT = timezone(timedelta(hours=-4))

spring_ahead_159am = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 1, 59, 59, tzinfo = EST)
spring_ahead_3am = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo = EDT)
    
(spring_ahead_3am - spring_ahead_159am).seconds
1
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: [aware datetime arithmetic](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html) blog post by Paul Ganssle. If you ask me, Python timedeltas with aware datetime are a bit of a pain ^^ If you want the absolute/UTC time difference, you can use e.g. `spring_ahead_3am.astimezone(tz.UTC)-spring_ahead_159am.astimezone(tz.UTC)`.

Comment: @MrFuppes But when I am doing the same manually with timedelta it works and give me 1 second. Why here I need all the .dst and astimezone(tz.UTC) stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by manually?

Comment: Using these settings and then subtracting:
```EST = timezone(timedelta(hours=-5))
EDT = timezone(timedelta(hours=-4))```

Comment: @MrFuppes I mean put it instead of the eastern tzinfo inside the datetime function in my question.
Why it will work easily with EST and EDT defined in my previous comment but doesn't work with tz?

Comment: Those are static UTC offsets. The issue you're experiencing in the first part of the question (with the time zone) only exists because of the DST transition (which doesn't exist with static tz).

Comment: @MrFuppes that's why I need or to make it the same tz (UTC) or do what Tim suggested?
Can you please explain the .dst() part in his answer?

Comment: "*need or to make it the same tz (UTC)*": equal tz you already have, but you'll want a tz that has no DST - ideally UTC. I think it is better not to fumble with the `DST` attribute. Use `astimezone(UTC)` or the Unix time as Tim added to his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little quirk of datetime objects.  Quoting from the documentation:

3. Subtraction of a datetime from a datetime is defined only if both operands are naive, or if both are aware. If one is aware and the other is naive, TypeError is raised.

   If both are naive, or both are aware and have the same tzinfo attribute, the tzinfo attributes are ignored, and the result is a timedelta object t such that datetime2 + t == datetime1. No time zone adjustments are done in this case.

You can certain get what you want by subtracting their DST components:

```
>>> spring_ahead_3am - spring_ahead_3am.dst() - spring_ahead_159am + spring_ahead_159am.dst()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

**Update**

Consider using this function, which does the Right Thing across timezones and DST changes:

```
def datesub( dt1, dt2 ):
    return datetime.timedelta( seconds=dt2.timestamp()-dt1.timestamp() )
```

Comment: actually, I'd say it's a quirk of timedelta objects. they show wall time difference for aware datetime, basically *as if there was no DST change*. The expected output of 1s would be absolute time difference. See also the blog post I linked under the question.

Comment: But when I am doing the same manually with timedelta it works and give me 1 second.
Why here I need all the .dst and astimezone(tz.UTC) stuff?

Comment: When you're doing what manually?  Show us the commands you're using that don't fail, and we'll explain the difference.

Comment: @TimRoberts please look at my comments above (comments to the question)

Comment: @TimRoberts what doest the .dst() gives us? Does it mean my datetime will be converted to UTC? For example spring_ahead_3am - spring_ahead_3am.dst() means that it will be in UTC?

Comment: Look, these folks have made a design decision that I do not particularly support. The issue arises when subtracting two datetimes that have identical embedded TZ info, and I think they do it wrong.  As a side note, if you do `spring_ahead_3am.timestamp() - spring_ahead_159am.timestamp()`, you will get `1`.  So, it's clear they know the right answer, and I don't know why the subtraction produces the wrong info.  Using `.dst()` compensates for what I also consider to be a bug.

Comment: I once had a discussion with Paul about this timedelta absolute vs. wall time thing in Python. It's a design decision, I don't think it's "wrong" or buggy. You can do it the one or the other way, but there will always be some unhappy customer... So the question I think is *can I get my work done with how it is implemented*, not *do I like the implementation*. Btw. using `timestamp()` here is basically the same as using `astimezone(UTC)` since Unix time has its reference point (epoch) in UTC time.

Comment: And to make the picture even more complicated, there's different implementations of the issue in question in different Python packages! For example `pandas` gives you absolute timedelta by default (I assume because the datetime implementation it uses has UTC as default (not local time as it is with Python standard lib's datetime)).

Comment: Thank you so much for this great discussion!

Comment: @MrFuppes, I do appreciate your insight. However, if we have two `datetime` values with timezone information, whether the same or different, then we have the ability to convert those -- confidently -- to universal timestamps with a common epoch.  In that case, how could it ever NOT be the right choice to subtract those timestamps?

Comment: "*NOT be the right choice*" - I did not mean to imply that. It is correct under the given circumstances. I'd just say using `astimezone` is more explicit about what's happening, thus more readable. But that's personal preference I guess :)